# md-virtual-repeat not working wiht md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to implement `md-virtual-repeat` for md-select which has more than 2000 items to select. This not working with the md-option.

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="break.start_time" md-on-open="vm.mdSelectOnOpen()">
        <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
            <md-option md-virtual-repeat="option in vm.time" value="option.value" >{{option.text}}</md-option>
        </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

What is the problem with this? [I have updated a plunker with my problem. see](https://plnkr.co/edit/bbHIzMXTjoQ9BoVr2qgD)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

Since you are using md-virtual select the check boxes you can refer the below codepen, there was no need to add a check box itself since md-select has an attribute called multiple which will add the check boxes

**Code**

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Select an option</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedOption" md-on-open="mdSelectOnOpen()" multiple>
       <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
         <md-option md-virtual-repeat="option in options" ng-value="option" ng-selected="selectedOption.indexOf(option) > -1">{{option}}</md-option>
      </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

**Codepen:** [here](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/KveWEB)

**Old Answer**

You need to give ng-selected option and ng-value.

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="break.start_time" md-on-open="vm.mdSelectOnOpen()">
        <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
            <md-option md-virtual-repeat="option in vm.time" ng-value="option.value" ng-selected="break.start_time==option.value">{{option.text}}</md-option>
        </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Refer: [codepen](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/rzvGbj)

Comment: thanks for the reference, I got the this where you shared from, but it's not working with me.

Comment: @MohamedNizar then share code, else can't debug, I mean jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: @MohamedNizar Thanks for the plunkr, I have updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: can you share the link

Comment: @ Naren Murali the Codepen version is working, but I need to work with Plunker that I shared with you.It's  only describe my problem. see this link.https://plnkr.co/edit/bbHIzMXTjoQ9BoVr2qgD?p=preview

Comment: @Mohamed, I think you can figure out the rest, please use my example as reference

Comment: @MohamedNizar were you able to fix it?

Comment: Not yet, I have created an issue in github, see.https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10868

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe this can help to someone.
If the following did not work

```js
$scope.$broadcast("$md-resize")
```

use this instead:

```js
angular.element(window).triggerHandler('resize')
```